# Birkhoff spectrum is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $f:X\to X$ be a homemmorphim on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that $T:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. We consider
$$
\sigma_{f}(x):=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T(f^{k}(x).$$

$\textbf{Question}$: Why is
$$W(\alpha):=\{x \in X, \sigma_{f}(x)=\alpha\}$$
not compact?

$W(\alpha)$ is the set of point where the limit of $\sigma_{f}(x)$ exists.
I know the set might be an empty set(consider the identity functions), so consider the question in case the set is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "not always compact" (since for the identity map $\sigma_{Id}(x)=T(x)$ and so $W(\alpha)=T^{-1}(\alpha)$ which is a (possibly empty) compact set).

I don't know what kind of answer in terms of "why" you may be looking for, but one type of example is that $T$ has a repelling fixed point $x_0$ and all the nearby $x$ proceed to a different Birkhoff average, while $x_0$ stays and gets its own average. Consider:

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x^2$, and $T(x)=x$. We then have $\sigma_f(x)=\lim \frac{1}{n}(x+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2^{n-1}})$ which is $1$ if $x=1$ and is  zero for all other $x$. This means $W(0)=[0,1)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to realize that $\sigma_f$ need not be continuous under your assumptions.

> Actually, in many situations it turns out that $W(\alpha)$ is dense but not compact for $\alpha$ in some interval. This is the case for example for the dynamics on a hyperbolic set and Hölder continuous functions.
>
> The main reference for this type of results is L. Barreira and J. Schmeling, *Sets of “non-typical” points have full topological entropy and full Hausdorff dimension*, Israel J. Math. **116** (2000), 29–70.

*Incidentally, you need of course to clarify what you mean by "the limit exists for almost every point".*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please give an example for the dynamics on a hyperbolic set and Hölder continuous functions that $W(\alpha)$ is not compact? because that is what I am looking for it.

Comment: @Adam Sure, I have updated my answer. To give explicit examples is easy since it works basically for all of them (better to see the reference).

Comment: Thank you very much.